# Counting the number of elements whose class names are partially matching

Tags: cypress

How do I count the number of tabs in cypress given that the class names of both the tabs are `walkme-1-tab-name` and `walkme-2-tab-name`?

As class names are slightly different, I want to count the number of classes which matches such a pattern - in the above example it is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Partial matching requires some special characters in the selector

**Starts with, using ^ char**

```js
cy.get('[class^="walkme"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
```

**Ends with, using $ char**

```js
cy.get('[class$="tab-name"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
```

**Contains, using * char**

```js
cy.get('[class*="tab"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
```

**Combination**

```js
cy.get('[class^="walkme"][class$="tab-name"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
```